# What’s the difference between ‘as much, if not more, than’ and ‘as much, if not more, as’?

Tags: expressions

When I found *as much, if not more, than*, I had an impression that *than* might be wrong at first because the phrase looked like a variation of *as much as*. However, there’re a lot of examples of both of them on the Net. Do they have different meanings?

1. as much, if not more, than (*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix (5)* [US Version]: p501)

> He was no longer their sullen host of the summer; now he seemed determined that everyone should enjoy themselves as much, if not more, than they would have done at Hogwarts, and he worked tirelessly in the run-up to Christmas Day, cleaning and decorating with their help, so that by the time they all went to bed on Christmas Eve the house was barely recognizable.

1. as much, if not more, as (From Google search)

> The imports in 1877 amounted to as much, if not more, as in 1876, though I have not been able to procure the exact figures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both examples have odd syntax. Written in full, the first would be:

> . . . he seemed determined that everyone should enjoy themselves as
>   much as they would have done at Hogwarts, if not more than they would
>   have done at Hogwarts . . .

To express the same thing elliptically it is necessary to write:

> . . . he seemed determined that everyone should enjoy themselves as
>   much as, if not more, than they would have done at Hogwarts . . .

Applying the same process to the second example, we get:

> The imports in 1877 amounted to as much as those in 1876, if not more
>   than those in 1876.

Elliptically:

> The imports in 1877 amounted to as much as, if not more than, those 
>   in 1876

Comment: Exactly. The standard way of writing this is "as much as, if not more than". These citations are dropping one of the prepositions in a way prescriptive grammarians would disapprove of. All of these phrases mean the same thing. And judging from Google books, they are all three used roughly equally often.

Comment: Anecdotally, I find *as much if not more than* to be "normal"-sounding (*...enjoy themselves as much, if not more, than they would have done...* reads fine to me and I don't notice that *as much as* has lost a preposition), whereas *as much if not more as* is nearly unparseable for me on first read. I guess I'm looking for a *than* or I have trouble with the sequential *more as*.

Comment: @Barrie England Thanks for your kind explanation. That was easy to understand.

Comment: @Peter Shor Your comment put the finishing touch to my understanding. Great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @aedia λ Extremely interesting. (I guess I’m reading English like a machine. It’s a long and winding road for me to read English smoothly.)

Comment: @PeterShor: The British National Corpus is inconclusive, having two records for ‘as much if not more than’ and one for ‘as much as if not more than’. The comparable figures for the Corpus of Contemporary American English are far more decisive: eleven and two.

Answer (score 0):

The mathematical equivalent of this expression is "greater than or equal to"; technically it means the same as "at least as much as":

> he seemed determined that everyone should enjoy themselves **as much, if
>   not more, than** they would have done at Hogwarts

could be rewritten as

> he seemed determined that everyone should enjoy themselves **at least
>   as much as** they would have done at Hogwarts

Literally the expression is a shorthand way of saying "if they do **not** enjoy them selves **more than** they would have done at Hogwarts, they should enjoy themselves **as much as** they would have done at Hogwarts".

Answer (score 0):

The two relevant phrases are ***as much as*** and ***more than***. Grammatically, *as much than* and *more as* are nonsensical; thus, any sentence that attributes *than* or *as* to both phrases is mistaken.

Correct usage:

> *X is **as much as** Y.*
>
> *X is **more than** Y.*
>
> *X is **as much as**, if not **more than**, Y.*

Incorrect usage:

> *X is **as much than** Y.*
>
> *X is **more as** Y.*
>
> *X is **as much**, if not more, **than** Y.*
>
> *X is as much, if **not more, as** Y.*